# Select a particular value from the data grid that is pulled dynamically

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find a particular "Incident Number" from the table that is visible in the data grid that is generated dynamically. How can I access this?

Attached is the table view of the page from where I'm trying to see if the Incident number is present in the table or not.
[image: TableView]

Here is the html code, where I'm trying to access verify if the highlighted Incident number is present in this page or not,

[image: htmCodeForDataGrid]

Comment: From the HTML DOM, it's evident that columns are identified using <div> element. What about rows? What HTML elements are used to create that? It would be really nice if you can provide html for the full data grid. That would help us to create a solution to your problem.

Comment: I uploaded the html file(dynamicData) to this site. Please  use this link to download it, http://wikisend.com/download/525032/dynamicData.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to iterate through the data grid rows to find out the Incident Number expected i.e **INC000006300863.** Once we find out the incident number, we will store the row number and click on the check-box present on the same row. Coding will look like something below:

```
String xpath_rows = "//div[@class='ngCanvas']//div[contains(@class, 'Row')]";
String expectedIncidentNumber = "INC000006300863";
int numberOfRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath_rows)).size();
int matchedRow;

// Find out row number for **INC000006300863** incident number
for(int i=1; i<=numberOfRows; i++)
{

   if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath_rows +"[" +i +"]//a[contains(text(), 'INC')]")).getText().equals(expectedIncidentNumber))
   {

      matchedRow = i;
      break;

   }

}

// Click on the checkbox present on the matched row
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath_rows +"[" +i +"]//input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
```

Hope it helps!